# Is it OK to plant flowering plants near my herb garden?

Tags: flowers, herbs, pest-damage

I have mint, tarragon, sweet basil etc. Beside is another plot for different kinds of roses and daises. Then the roses started to lose leaves or have bites on the leaves. Do the herbs attract insects that cause this?

Comment: No. Insects don't distinguish between herbs, veggies and ornamental plants. They choose between "tasty" and "bleech".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anything, I have heard arguments (likely anecdotal) that plants like Tarragon and Basil actually repel some insects, possibly at a range of a few feet. Roses on the other hand, tend to be victimized by a wide range of insects and diseases regardless of what they are planted near. They are not exactly a low maintenance plant.  I would suggest searching through our questions on [roses](/questions/tagged/roses). If nothing there looks like what you're seeing on your roses post a question about it with a picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since I posted this broad question, but over the years of experience in gardening and finding helpful resources online, I was able to discover companion planting for cut flowers [[1](https://florgeous.com/companion-planting/)]  and for vegetables [[2](https://www.almanac.com/companion-planting-guide-vegetables)].

All plants, including ornamentals and cut flowers, attract and/or repel different sets of pests. It is best to find reputable resources about which plants go together. Also, the climate, zone, season, and environment are also some major factors to consider as it can affect which pests and diseases normally exist.

For medium to large-scale vegetable or cut-flower production, synthetic pesticides seem to be practical to maintain a good profit. But for home gardening, small-scale farming, and hobby farming, avoiding pesticides will benefit the surrounding community in the long term. Some saying goes that "if nothing eats your plants, then it is not part of the ecosystem."

For organic gardening, insects in general are not necessarily enemies, but companion planting is one option, aside from bio-pesticides, that may aid in minimizing the effects of pest damage.

For roses, geranium may repel pests, but other factors apply, including soil quality as plant health is integral to overall plant survival from pests. As for most vegetables, French marigolds and chrysanthemums has pesticidal and deterrent properties. It can be planted near the vegetables or used as a bio-pesticide spray.

When using both synthetic and bio-pesticides, skip broad-spectrum products and just focus on the specific pests attacking the plants, if possible implement manual 'squishing' of pests.